# Asp.Net - Issue while working with grid which contains a user control as item template

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, user-controls, postback

I have a user control and the user control is having a grid and some buttons inside that.
Inside the grid I added user control as item template. So while binding the grid,it contains multiple number of usercontrols as row inside the grid. All those are inside a radajaxpanel.

Now in my user control there is a button called btnSave. I am triggering the postback from by using a javascript.
by `__doPostBack('btnSave','someValue');` So its triggers postback and working fine.While clicking save I am updating the grid.Its working fine. But if the grid contains 10 items (ie 10 user controls) it will trigger 10 postbacks and updates the other grids also. How to avoid the extra post back and avoid binding other grids.

What I tried.

using clientID and uniqueiD. Post back works but the binding is not working. The grid is not updating. When I changed it to
'btnSave' all are working, but other grids inside the usercontrol also get binded.

I hope my issue is clear and thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Team, I changed my solution description. Please have a look into it.

Comment: please add some code snippets of what you've tried and I'm sure you'll get the help you need